# There seems to be a subtle difference between the infinitive form of the verb 'to be' after a verb and the inflected form of the same; what is it?

Tags: verbs, be, inflections

There seems to be a subtle difference between the infinitive form of the verb 'to be' after a verb and the inflected form of the same; what is it?

This effect, if there is one, seems most noticeable in (or only applies to) some sentences that reference a subject's beliefs.

> John claims to be Michael Jackson's reincarnation.
>
> John claims that he is Michael Jackson's reincarnation.
>
> ---
>
> John believes Michael Jackson to be reincarnated.
>
> John believes that Michael Jackson is reincarnated.

If the inflected and infinitive form of the verb 'to be' convey things that are subtly different, what is that difference?

Comment: There is a grammatical difference, but semantically, the two constructions mean precisely the same thing to me. I can’t squeeze out even the slightest difference in nuance between them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If I didn't have reason to believe otherwise, I'd agree with you (this isn't only based on a hunch).

Comment: Please update your question, in that case, to reflect what it is that makes you think that it is so.

Comment: My intuition is that there is a differnce in the degree of formality, but I have no evidence to support it.

Comment: This is discussed in a similar context [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110798/15299).

Comment: By the way, the second phrase should be "John claims **that** he is...," using a noun clause.

Comment: To my ear there is a little more of the speaker's suspicion/doubt in the veracity of the claim with the infinitive construction.  It's slight, though.  And I agree with Barrie England above that the infinitive construction also reads as more formal.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My hunch is based on some notions in epistemology; the relevant ideas are related to everyday English, but I think that they require too much reading about non-English matters for too little information about the matter in question. On that thinking, I decided not to post them.

Answer (score 1):

First, those constructions are more different *grammatically*, more so than meaning. *To be* functions differently in your examples (neither is wrong and their meanings are the same); it's not functioning as a verb. Full infinitives usually function as other parts of speech.

> *John* (subject) *claims* (verb) *to be Michael Jackson's reincarnation* (noun clause/object).
>
> *John* (subject of 1st clause) *claims* (verb) *that* (conjucntion) *he is* (2nd clause with *he as subject* and *is as verb*) *Michael Jackson's reincarnation* (noun clause/object of 2nd clause).

Second, **if forced to say there were a difference**--which there isn't, frankly--it'd be the degree of certainty. The infinitive forms (i.e. *to be*) indicate that the assertion is less certain than when you use the inflected form (i.e. in this case, *is*). In other words *John believes that Michael Jackson is reincarnated.* is the strong/emphatic--for lack of a better word--form.

Also, I believe that it is an issue of formality, but I can't locate a source to confirm that.

Comment: Basically, I agree. It's subtle, but in the example given, "to be" seems to hold the claim at arms length, to imply a more cynical pose. "To be" feels colder, "is" feels warmer & more on-the-nose.

Answer (score 0):

According to Michael Swan (Practical English Usage 2nd Edition), in an informal style, after such verbs, 
*-that* constructions are more common.  Also, *-that* can be dropped to make sentences just that little bit more informal.

Comment: You're right in that, when used as a conjunction, that can sometimes be omitted; but that only works with certain [verbs](http://www.pugetsound.edu/about/offices-services/office-of-communications/style-guides/style-guide/style-guide-t/). I'd say better to add *that* than omit it. Extraneous isn't necessarily wrong.