# What are some ways of getting around the overuse of the the indefinite it (or at least using it too much)?

Tags: grammar, phrases, pronouns

It seems to me there are simply too many *it's* in use today (you see, I just used one without thinking).

*It* is a very fine word, to be sure, and performs many useful services. Its overuse, however, seems to me--at times and with some writers--to be an unnecessary  crutch or even a shortcut bypassing inventiveness and style. Perhaps an over-dependence on the use of *it* results in sentences which are less concrete and more passive sounding than they could or should be.

For example, instead of saying, "It occurs to me there is a much simpler solution to the problem," why not say "In my opinion there is a much simpler solution to the problem" (or simply "I think there is a simpler solution to the problem")?

A good answer would contain sentences which could be improved by removing the indefinite *it*. If the answerer would like to go a little deeper into the grammatical ramifications of the overuse of *it*, I won't object. (Note: I am a fairly decent rhetorician, but only a so-so grammarian.)

What I'm really after, however, are some artful ways of eliminating the the word *it* from sentences.

For example, why couldn't the following sentence lose the *it* without damaging the sentence and its meaning?

> *It* is a travesty the way President Trump uses the English language.

Or,

> *It* is hard to conceive how best to solve the immigration problem we have in America.

Or,

> *It* appeals to me the way Joe Blow expresses himself.

Or,

> *It's* a matter of taste when *it* comes to evaluating how appropriately and skillfully food is seasoned.

Or,

> When the biggest platforms seem to be flailing or punting on problems, *it’s* often because they’re trying to address broad social issues with market solutions.

Comment: Why do you say it's overused? Why pick on _it_ when _the_ and _of_ are much more common and troublesome? Can you give any example sentences, with reasons why they shouldn't use _it_? As it is, it seems you simply have a distaste for it, but can't specify how or why. This is where "unclear what you're asking" comes in.

Comment: You really should provide some examples yourself, with alternatives, and say what you think is wrong with them.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Sorry I took so long in providing my own answer. I've provided some examples. I'm hoping to get more of them from interested answerers. Don

Comment: @bof You are correct. I have updated the tags used.

Comment: You might try posting your question to the Writers' SE site.

Comment: It has its uses and its merits.

Comment: @StuW: Good idea, Stu. I seem to be attracting a lot of negative press on this site, at least regarding this question. Two possible factors at work. First, rhetoricians and grammarians don't mix. Kinda like oil and water. Second, my question seems to some to be a gripe or or a pet peeve, the kind of question  to be eschewed on this site. I don't mind being considered a gadfly, but I don't think the title is deserved, at least in this case. Maybe I should gather up my marbles and go elsewhere! (I'm just being a little jocular.) Thanks for the referral to Writers SE. Don

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to reply to this in sequence, partly based on what's given in the question and partly on what was relayed in some comments.

> It seems to me there are simply too many *it's* in use today.

The word is an important element of English, and I don't agree that there are *too many* of them. It seem obvious that you don't like the word for some reason, but I think you'd be in a minority when it comes to actually advocating against it—or wanting to change our language to remove it.

> It occurs to me . . .
> In my opinion . . .

You asked why have the first sentence form instead of the second. In my view, neither sentence is an "improvement" over the other. There is a subtle difference of meaning (I interpret the first to be about you *becoming aware* of something and the second to be about you *already having* a belief), but nothing really noteworthy. The choice between the two is simply a matter of personal preference.

But compare the full version of the original to something with even greater parsing:

> It occurs to me there is a much simpler solution to the problem.
> There is a simpler solution.

Now that *does* make a difference. It's far simpler and more direct. The meaning has been changed, but I don't believe greatly enough to lose its essential quality. (Especially if context has already been established for the sentence.)

Here, it's not about replacing *it* with a non-*it* word, but actually using the fewest number of words to make the same basic point. It just so happens that in removing half the words, *it* was one of them.

> For example, why couldn't the following sentence lose the *it* without damaging the sentence and its meaning?
>
> *It* is a travesty the way President Trump uses the English language.

Try:

> President Trump's use of English is a travesty.

That's shorter and more direct. *It* has been removed, but I didn't rewrite the sentence with that intention specifically.

Let's look at some more simplifications:

> *It* is hard to conceive how best to solve the immigration problem we have in America.
> America's immigration problem is hard to solve.
>
> It appeals to me the way Joe Blow expresses himself.
> I like how Joe Blow expresses himself.
>
> It's a matter of taste when it comes to evaluating how appropriately and skillfully food is seasoned.
> Skillful food seasoning is a matter of taste.

All of these rewrites remove the word *it*. But it isn't the use of *it* specifically that was the problem. It was the construction of the sentences that all *began* with *it*. Which isn't to say that beginning a sentence with *it* is always bad:

> It's raining.
> It was a poor attempt.

Here, I can think of no way of making the sentences shorter or clearer by removing the word *it*. In fact, if they were rephrased to remove that specific word, I think the sentences would be slightly awkward:

> There is rain.
> A poor attempt was made.

---

Let's consider a rephrasing example you gave in a comment (which I have simplified slightly):

> It is not difficult to understand Strauss's about-face.
> To understand Strauss's about-face is not difficult.

I find the rephrased version *more* difficult to parse. Why?

Verb phrase: (It is not difficult to understand)
Noun: (Strauss's about-face)

Verb phrase, part 1: (To understand . . .)
Noun: (Strauss's about-face)
Verb phrase, part 2: ( . . . is not difficult.)

In the rephrased version, the flow of reading the verb phrase is *interrupted* by the noun. This is an annoyance, and makes the understanding of the complete sentence reliant on an interrupted thought, since full parsing can only happen in "hindsight."

Let me suggest a different rephrasing:

> It is not difficult to understand Strauss's about-face.
> Steve's about-face is easily understood.

I find this much better. There is no "interruption" and everything is easily parsed without *it*.

---

Where does this leave me?

I actually think that, in analysis, you are partially correct in saying that if you rephrase certain sentences to remove *it* that it results in a simpler, more easily understood sentence.

My initial opposition to this suggestion was coloured by the fact that I found *your* rephrased versions more difficult to read. Not because they were missing *it* but because the rephrasing involved "mental interruptions."

However, I don't think that it's actually *it* itself that you object to but the fact that it makes vague some sentences that have been too-quickly constructed with it. Your objection isn't to *it* per se, but to a lack of plain language in general.

Comment: +1. Some good stuff. However (uh-oh, a big but--not b-u-t-t--is coming) . . .. When, for example, an antecedent earlier in the sentence or in a preceding sentence is understood clearly, I have no problem using "it." When the antecedent is not clear, I think rephrasing the sentence by eliminating "it" makes good sense. When, for example, someone says "It's raining," chances are they are not saying "It's raining" in a vacuum. A person probably said to them, "What's the weather like today in Podunk?" Response: "It's raining." The antecedent to "it's" is "weather." Poor example? Maybe.

Comment: See my last example of an "improved" sentence in my answer. I just added it. Thoughts? Don

Comment: In terms of simplification? I'd prefer "Large platforms struggle when they apply inappropriate solutions to perceived problems.*"

Answer (score -2):

The word *it* can indeed be a shortcut bypassing inventiveness and style. Without further ado, following are a few sentences which could be improved by eliminating the indefinite *it*. Notice I have characterized each "before" sentence as *adequate*, and each "after" sentence as *improved*.

- **Adequate**: It is difficult to imagine that the glorious tone poems of Richard Strauss (1864-1949) were a subject of boiling controversy around the turn of the [20th] century.

  > **Improved**: To imagine that the glorious tone poems of Richard Strauss . . . were a subject of boiling controversy . . . is difficult.
- **Adequate**:  In retrospect, it is not difficult to understand Strauss's about-face.

  > **Improved**:  In retrospect, to understand Strauss's about-face is not difficult.
- **Adequate**:  It is fascinating to consider the direction Strauss *might* have taken, although no one who has fallen under the spell of his next major work, Der Rosenkavalier (1911), could regret his staunch reaffirmation of tradition.

  > **Improved**: To consider the direction Strauss *might* have taken is fascinating, although no one who has fallen under the spell of his next major work, *Der Rosenkavalier* (1911), could regret his staunch reaffirmation of tradition.
  >
  > **Or, also improved**:  To consider the direction Strauss *might* have taken I find fascinating . . ..
- **Adequate**: When the biggest platforms seem to be flailing or punting on problems, it’s often because they’re trying to address broad social issues with market solutions.

  > **Improved**: The biggest platforms seem to be flailing or punting on problems because they're trying to address broad social issues with market solutions.

Comment: First of all, this should be edited into the question itself, not given as an answer. But why are the **improved** versions better? You haven't provided any reasoning behind why somebody should do this. Currently it's just "I don't like to see the word." You need something more compelling than that . Or are you asking for some kind of general grammatical rule that could be used by people who want to reconstruct these sentences—something that could be "easily" followed?

Comment: How about "To Tipperary is a long way" or "Cold is out today"? Are these improvements?

Comment: @Jason: Good points. Perhaps sentences which are less indefinite and more concrete, containing more action, are preferable. Instead of saying the more passive-sounding "It is difficult to imagine the Strauss tone poems as controversial" why not say "I have difficulty believing that Strauss's tone poems were controversial"? Again, I'm not a grammarian, but isn't active construction usually better than passive (except perhaps in situations where diplomacy is paramount).

Comment: @JohnLawler: If you're Yoda, to me I think they sound quite normal and natural. Seriously, however, please read my comment to Jason; perhaps it will clarify what I'm getting at. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Interesting. I find the opposite effect. Your original sentences are more direct (active), while your rephrased versions seem "poetic" but also more long-winded and indirect (passive). Mainly, your rephrased versions move the "important" part of the sentence to the end—you have to read more to understand what the sentence is discussing. Compare *eating fish is my favourite thing* with *of many things, eating fish is my favourite*. I'm *hooked* (no pun intended) within the first two words of the first sentence. But I don't immediately know what I'm reading about in the second.

Comment: @rhetorician Good revision of your question; I removed my close vote. If you can also add the information in your comment here (starting with "Good points") into the question, then I can actually take a stab at giving my own answer. (You can reply to my other comment in your question too.)

Comment: @JasonBassford. I think I incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: @rhetorician: this is all still a mishmash of what you like and don't like, with no reasons, but lots of handwaving. You ask why a few extraposed sentences "can't lose the _it_ without damaging the sentence and its meaning". Of course, except in a few cases, extraposition is optional, so there is no damage involved, and no meaning change, either. It's speaker's choice, like most things. And "passive" has a particular meaning in grammar, which has nothing to do with the examples you provide; better not use the term if you don't know what it means.

Comment: @JohnLawler: ". . . better not use the term"? Them's fightin' words, John. Put up your dukes! Seriously, though, I just looked up the term extraposition. As I said in my post, "I'm a so-so grammarian," so be gentle with me. As for my use of the term passive, I'm not using the term as a grammarian would but as a person who is struggling to describe the difference between "It puzzles me why my question is generating so much negative press" and "I'm puzzled why my question is generating so much negative press." Maybe my overactive imagination is to blame. I don't know.

Comment: There is no difference between them, except what a given listener or reader might conjure up from their normally active imaginations. That's pragmatics, not syntax or semantics, if you want to have terminology. Extraposition is just one of several ways English has developed since it lost all its inflections over the last millennium to get "heavy" subjects (long strings, phrases, or clauses) out of the subject position and shifted to the end of the sentence, where they're easier to process, since English is right-branching.

Comment: [A couple more](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/110798/15299) references [on the subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+heavy+subject) of heavy subjects.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks for the referrals. I'm afraid much of the content of those links is way above my pay grade. I'm just a lowly rhetorician. And yes, we rhetoricians tend to focus on pragmatics. You know, the who, what, when, where, how, and why, vis a vis English usage. I genuflect to your superiority in all things grammatical, semantical, and syntactical (Note: I'm not being ironic or sardonic here). I stand tall and proud, however, when defending the power  of English usage to inspire, persuade, inform, and entertain within the rubrics of act, scene, agent, agency, purpose, and motive.

Comment: Then you'd probly enjoy Levinson's _Pragmatics_ and Green's _Pragmatics and Natural Language Understanding_, as well as the pragmatics chapters of McCawley's _Everything that Linguists Have Always Wanted to Know about Logic (but were ashamed to ask)_